# Cant boot windows 10 after installing ubuntu

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, grub2

I double booted Ubuntu 20.04 using USB. I also have a 256 GB SSD AND 1 TB HDD. I made partition myself giving 200 GB for /home folder and 75 GB for root folder . 145 gb of ssd is allotted to windows OS. But now when I try booting windows It makes me choose keyboard layout and brings me to the advanced recovery options screen where there are three option . Boot from USB , troubleshoot or shut down system.
I can access the windows partition from Ubuntu file manager.
Tried running boot-repair. https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/vQ6zxKNY2b/

Comment: goto your bios and set windows boot option to no.1 and see if you can boot into windows or not.

Comment: i have UEFI settings and there windows in not showing up in boot options, but it is showing up in grub options.

Comment: is your windows installed in bios mode?

Comment: it is UEFI bios not in legacy mode

Comment: try to make a windows 10 live usb through media creation tool and try to boot into that and select fix startup see maybe that fix something

Answer (score -1):

Maybe you're booting into the recovery partition of Windows instead of the Windows OS Partition. And you may have corrupted Windows partition by mistake during space allocation.

Can you please provide some other details like :
How are you booting into Windows? through GRUB or BIOS?
How did you allocated the storage? during Ubuntu installation or previously in Windows?

Additional details will help understand your issue correctly.

Comment: I am trying to login using grub.First i unallocated space both in my ssd and HDD from windows by shrinking volume. Then I installed Ubuntu  chose something else option at the time of memory allocation and then allocated the unallocated memories to Ubuntu.

Comment: I think you have to recreate the partition table for both the drives to avoid further issues. But it will remove all your files.

Comment: okk. Thank you for the help